# R言語にアンドゥ・リドゥはございますでしょうか？

Tags: .net, r

お世話になっております。

現在Windows7（64Bit)、VisualBasic（.NetFramework4.0）、R.NETを介してRとやり取りをするアプリケーションを作ろうとしています。

表題の件につきまして、所謂Rに対して行った作業について取消しややり直しをウィンドウズフォームアプリケーションで実現したく思っております。

R言語のコマンドやR.NETの仕様にあるかと思いオンラインドキュメント等を見ているのですが思った通りの物が見つかりません。

どなたかご存知の方おられましたらヒント等頂けますでしょうか？

リドゥはコマンドの履歴があるのでなんとでもなりそうです。

しかしアンドゥの方はワークスペースを世代毎に管理しておけばなんとかなるかもしれませんがもっとスマートな方法があるかと思い質問させて頂いた次第であります。

恐らくワークスペースにはどのモジュールがロードされているか等の情報がなかったと思うので出来れば避けたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コマンドの履歴を最初から実行しなおして一つ手前で止めれば実質的にアンドゥになりませんか？

Comment: h2so5さま

ご示唆ありがとうございます。
確かにその通りですが履歴が多くなるというかRの使用目的の性質上、重たい処理が間に多くなると履歴の状況によっては処理が重たくなりそうです。

しかし整合性の上ではこれ以上のものはないでしょうから他に適当な案がなければ採用したく思います。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自分の知る限りでは見たことないので、所望の操作の履歴を持つ永続データ構造をご自身で実装するしかないと思います。